# Weekly or daily rotation of promo image slider

Tags: java, web

We have configurable length promos on site eg.. if i set 8 then on front website display 8 promo images.

Now i want to develop like rotation promos in weekly or daily basis.
for eg.. if i have 24 promos and i set weekly rotation then first week display 1st 8 then second week display next 8 and so on.. and when all items done then it will display from starting.

1. We need to have the ability to display any given number of product in that section of the homepage. it set to 8, but this could change to 16, etc.
2. If for example it's configured for 8 products but there are 33 active products, for the first week it will show 8 of the 33 , then the following week it will show the next 8 profiles.
3. The products shown on the first week should not be shown on the second week, we want to ensure all product get a spot on the rotation so if there are 24 products on the site and the  Gallery is configured to show 8. Then on week #1 we will see the first 8, then week #2 we see the next set of products then on week #3 it shows the remaining 8 products. Then after that it goes back to showing the original 8 that appeared on week #1.

Is it possible using circular linked list in java ?  any example or any hint please ?

```
public class Node{
        int data;
        List<String> ids;
        Node next;
        public Node(int data,List<String> ids) {
            this.data = data;
            this.ids = ids;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it a class assignment or practical app? IRL you're better off just dumping the whole images to DB or other storage, then do WEEK_OF_YEAR or DAY_OF_YEAR, modulo with how much set you have, and take the images from (setnumber * setsize) to (setnumber * setsize+setsize-1)

Comment: It's web app and images are represent products. and all images are stored in cloud. just i want to achieve all products display in weekly basis.

Comment: So it's not class assignment? List the image links in DB, and get them with the module I mentioned, your DB of choice must have a paging option for queries

Comment: Post your additional details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.